# disabling python script tracing, equivalent of turning off -x in bash

Tags: python, trace

I have python scripts which I'd like to disable tracing on. By tracing, I mean the ability to run:

```
python -m trace --tracing thescript.py
```

In bash, if you want to see the inner workings of a script, you can just run the following:

```
sh -x thescript.sh
```

or

```
bash -x thescript.sh
```

However, if `thescript.sh` contains a `set +x`; that will stop the external `sh -x` or `bash -x` from showing any further inner workings of the script past the line containing the `set +x`.

I want the same for python.  I'm only aware of `python -m trace --tracing` as the only way to see the inner workings of a python script. I'm sure there are many different ways to do this. What I'm looking for here is a solid method to use to stop any type of tracing that could be done to a python script.

I understand if a user has the proper permissions, they can edit the script and comment out whatever is put in to disable tracing.  I'm aware of that. But i would still like to know.

Comment: This isn't quite what you're asking for, but the [trace module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) has a programatic interface so that you can trace a just single function.

Comment: "What I'm looking for here is a solid method to use to stop any type of tracing that could be done to a python script."   Impossible.  Even if python wasn't interpreted (eg you ship the source) there's no way to give someone a computer program they can't analyze.

Comment: @DanielFarrell - I understand that.  I just want to know how to disable tracing, if it is at all possible.

Comment: Please don't use the `bash` tag for a question that bash expertise does not help to answer.

Comment: Funny thing, btw -- I just took an early lead in a CTF on account of the folks running it using a pyinstaller-bundled executable to hide a bunch of flags. [Unpack its contents, decompile the .pyc files](https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/pydeinstaller), and it's fun times from there.

Comment: (...which is to say, one of the ways this is like turning off `set -x` is that neither does any good whatsoever as an obfuscation measure if the person trying to reverse it is remotely competent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking even a cursory look at `trace.py` from the standard library makes the interfaces it uses, and thus the mechanism to disable them, clear:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, threading
sys.settrace(None)
threading.settrace(None)
print("This is not traced")
```

Of course, this won't (and can't) work against anyone who wants to modify the live interpreter to NOP out those calls; the usual caveats about anyone who owns and controls the hardware being able to own and control the software apply.